# SMPP SMS receiving speed

Tags: smpp

We have developed SMPP application. It's SMS receiving speed is mere 16 SMS per second.
How can i increase this speed?

Comment: It is receiving not sending? What is doing the sending - it looks like that application is not asynchronous and if so that is where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, I recommend getting JRat to profile the application. You need to know where to optimize before optimizing.

That being said, I went through this as well. The biggest bottleneck I encountered was the `ServerPDUEventListener` implementation - in my first version, I was treating all incoming PDUs in that class - which serialized access to them - and some were doing database access! The way I solved this is by spawning threads for the PDUs which I actually wanted to process in a more detailed manner - in my case this was the `DELIVER_SM` PDUs and the `SUBMIT_SM_RESP` PDUs but that depends on the actual application you are developing. Handling them in separate threads meant my main `ServerPDUEventListener` was free to keep processing the next PDUs. The bottleneck is similar to implementing a server socket - whenever you `accept` a client socket, you want to return to listening for other incoming connections and handle the communication in a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

What kindof application it is, written in Java?

Couple of things
1. See where it is taking most of the time in processing. This would lead to a solution
2. Can optimize the processing flow to queue and process the messages

There are other factor involved as well, like hardware configuration etc, but normal hardware gives a decent performance.

Comment: OpenSMPP is the java standard for connecting to mobile networks (it was developed by a firm called Logica I believe)

Comment: You may try Cloudhopper, too: https://github.com/twitter/cloudhopper-smpp.git . It is the library Twitter uses for SMPP.

Answer (score 0):

First of all process all incoming and outgoing sms in the asynchronous mode. For example in the jsmpp lib you can process all traffic in the asynchronous and synchronous mode. The first mode is mach faster.

If possible process all your heavy business logic in the separate threads and if possible for example in the enterprise java beans. If your traffic is very big and business logic too heavy   then using asynchronous mode in the smpp and enterprise java beans for business logic can very improve your application architecture.